# Splitting a string on special char

Tags: java, string

I have a string "0000_Clothing|0000_Clothing_Men's|0000_Clothing_Men's_Shirts", and i wanted to split this string on "|".

```
String CatArray[] = CatContext.split("|");
```

The above mentioned code is splitting the string into seperate characters like 0,0,0,0,_,C including the | symbol.

What Am i missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`|` is a regex metacharacter, escape it `"\\|"`

Comment: Should also mention that the first backslash is to escape the second backslash (due to Java), which escapes the | (due to regex syntax) :D

Answer (score 2):

Split method expects a regex and you will have to escape |

You can do either

```
CatContext.split("\\|");
```

or

```
CatContext.split("[|]");
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that [public String[] split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a **regex**.

So you should escape the [special char](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) `|`. Escaping a regex is done by `\`, but in Java, `\` is written as `\\`.

When you escape the special character, you're telling Java:

"Don't treat `|` as the special char `|`, treat it as it was the regular char `|`".

Another solution is to use [public static String quote(String s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) that "*Returns a literal pattern String for the specified String*":

`String[] CatArray = CatContext.split(Pattern.quote("|"));`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to deal with escaping the pipe (since pipe is a special regex character) then you can use `Pattern#quote`:

```
String[] catArray = CatContext.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
```

OR even simpler:

```
String[] catArray = CatContext.split("\\Q|\\E"));
```